# Is there a database/list of names, with their associated common diminutives?

Tags: выбор-имени

I'm looking for large lists of diminutives in Russian in a format such as this:

Base Name | [Diminutive1, Diminutive2, ...]

Comment: You'll be surprised to find out many popular Western names are actually Russian diminutives. :)

Comment: This site maintains a small example list of names... I was looking for a more comprehensive one: http://www.russian-language-for-lovers.com/russian-female-names.html

Answer (score 4):

It looks like by "nicknames" you mean diminutive forms of personal names. If so, then you can find a thorough list of them.

In the book "Справочник личных имен народов РСФСР" starting from [this page](http://padaread.com/?book=49840&pg=417), there is a list of personal names (first go male names, then female ones) together with their etymologies and diminutive forms. You can read the book online or download it.

Comment: Yes you are correct.  I do mean diminutives.  Nicknames are much broader.  I will edit the question.